# Determine the number of pair values in a given array

Tags: javascript, arrays

The following code is giving me the wrong result, any idea on how I can fix that? I need to get the number of pair values within an array that is passed to the function, n is the length of  arr which is the array itself.

```js
function TotalpairValues(n, arr) => {

  let pairs = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    let distinctValues = [];

    if (!dist.includes(arr[i])) {
      distinctValues.push(arr[i]);
    }

    for (let j = 0; j < distinctValues.length; j++) {

      if (distinctValues[i] === arr[i]) {
        pairs++;
        delete distinctValues[i];
      }
    }
  }
  return pairs;
}

var test = TotalpairValues(5, [2, 4, 2, 3, 4]);
console.log(test);
```

expected answer:

> **2**

when I run the code I get:

> 1

Comment: What is dist in line `if (!dist.includes(arr[i]))`?

Comment: Your code does not run at all...

Comment: That's a typo, I named the variable dist before changing to distinctValues, so when I made the changes to the variable, I missed to change that one line. It's supposed to read distinctValues sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is no need to use `distinctValues` as you want to count duplicate values. However, you can use `reduce` method to count duplicates and then just `filter` values which are not duplicate:

```
const result = arr.reduce((a, o) => {
  a[o] = a[o] || {o, count: 0};
  a[o].count += 1;
  return a;
},{})

let countDuplicates = Object.values(result).filter(f => f.count > 1).length;
```

An example:

```js
let arr = [2, 4, 2, 3, 4];
const result = arr.reduce((a, o) => {
  a[o] = a[o] || {o, count: 0};
  a[o].count += 1;
  return a;
},{})

let countDuplicates = Object.values(result).filter(f => f.count > 1).length;
console.log(countDuplicates);
```